# libavfilter thumbnail seems to only process first set of N frames

Tags: ffmpeg

According to the docs (see below) the '-vf thumbnail' should handle batches of N frames and pick 1 frame from each batch but it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong? I also tried various options with "-vframes 5" and 'out%d.png" but I got the same same frame repeated many times but it did process multiple batches of N frames.

8.37 thumbnail

Select the most representative frame in a given sequence of consecutive frames.

It accepts as argument the frames batch size to analyze (default N=100); in a set of N frames, the filter will pick one of them, and then handle the next batch of N frames until the end.

Since the filter keeps track of the whole frames sequence, a bigger N value will result in a higher memory usage, so a high value is not recommended.

The following example extract one picture each 50 frames:

thumbnail=50

Complete example of a thumbnail creation with ffmpeg:

ffmpeg -i in.avi -vf thumbnail,scale=300:200 -frames:v 1 out.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to set another one parameter `-vsync` (set it to 0 or 2), or muxer got wrong frames because by default `-vsync=1`

For example, correct command is

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE -vsync 0 -vf thumbnail,scale=300:200 -frames:v 20 -f image2 img-%04d.jpg
```

As for me, instead of thumbnail filter I use **I-frame** selector - its generate a little bit more files, but it more accurate for my purposes.
This is example with timestamp and firstly we are must find out correct fps from file (this is Mac OS X `grep` dialect) to set value of `r=`

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE 2>&1 | grep -Po "[^\s]+\sfps"
```

Also you are need select you own fontfile, I use Mac OS X files

Now all ready (f.e. save first 20 I-frames)

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE -someq -vsync 0 -vf \
drawtext="fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Courier\ New.ttf: \
timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':r=23.98: fontcolor=0xFFFFFFFF:fontsize=18:\
shadowcolor=0x000000EE:shadowx=1:shadowy=1",select='eq(pict_type\,I)'\
-vframes:v 20 -f image2 img-%04d.jpg
```

*(strange, I get error on `\`-spitted line, but all works in one-line)*